How to sign PowerShell module file?
I have created a PowerShell module and want to sign it and then will add to public repository.
I have tried below code
$TimeStampServer = “http://timestamp.digicert.com”
$PS1 = "C:\Users\naveen\Downloads\my.psm1"
$codeCert = Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My | Where-Object {$_.Subject -eq “CN=naveen”}
Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath $PS1 -Certificate $codeCert -TimeStampServer $TimeStampServer

But getting below error:
Set-AuthenticodeSignature : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Certificate' because it is null.

You probably want ... | Where-Object {$_.Subject -like "CN=naveen,*"}
